# What are the best practices for implementing the stencil store?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, components, stenciljs

When creating a Stencil store, is there a best practice when defining fields?

The documentation online only has basic examples of numbers, but what if we have objects, strings or booleans? Should we be using ‘as’ or ‘new’ keywords?

Example:

```
const { state, onChange } = createStore({
  username: null as string,
  friends: new List<Friends>(),
  isActive: false as boolean,  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `createStore()` function is generic so you can create an interface to define the types:

```
interface StoreState {
  username: string | null;
  friends: List<Friends>;
  isActive: boolean;
}

const { state, onChange } = createStore<StoreState>({
  username: null,
  friends: new List(),
  isActive: false,
});
```

Note that I removed the generic type in `List<Friends>` because that will automatically get inferred from the interface.

Comment: Thomas, this is great to know! There are many ways we could go about implementing the store. Do you think that there is a best way or up to preference?

Comment: In the end it's all up to preference, but I'd say this will scale better than other approaches. As you put more and more into the store it might also make sense to split it into multiple specialised stores.